# How to access Liferay's SessionErrors object from JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-6, jsp-tags

How can I access SessionErrors object from JSP? I've tried

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionErrors"%>

<%= SessionErrors.contains(request, "error-invalid-value") %> <br>
<%= SessionErrors.size(request) %>
```

but the result is false and 0. However, the error tag works fine (it shows the error thrown).

```
<liferay-ui:error key="error-invalid-value" message="error-invalid-value" />
```

In my controller, I set up the error like this:

```
//request is an ActionRequest.
SessionErrors.add(request, "error-invalid-value");
```

I am trying to test whether "error-invalid-value" error has been thrown or not.

If it helps, here is the tag's source code (I couldn't understand anything from it): https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/util-taglib/src/com/liferay/taglib/ui/ErrorTag.java

Answer (score 2):

one way to use this is

```
<liferay-ui:error key="error-invalid-value" 
   message="translation-key-for-the-message-to-be-shown" />
```

In case you've called `SessionErrors.add` like you stated in the question, this will show the message referenced. Otherwise it will show nothing.

Another way to use it (as it's only static methods) it to just use its regular interface in scriptlets or in your own tags:

```
<% if(SessionErrors.size(renderRequest) > 2) { %>
   Wow, you have triggered a lot of errors
<% } %>
```

Check the full [interface of SessionErrors](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/SessionErrors.html) to find more options to look for specific errors, access the whole keySet, or other information

Update: After your comments I've tried again and actually missed the `PortletRequest` parameters to SessionErrors: You can add errors with the `HttpServletRequest` or with the `PortletRequest` (e.g. `actionRequest`). When you add through the `ActionRequest`, you'll have to use the `PortletRequest` parameter to `SessionErrors.doSomething`, not the `HttpServletRequest`. On a JSP, `request` is a `HttpServletRequest`, while `renderRequest` is a `PortletRequest`. That's the one that you want to use in order to get your results.

Comment: Yes, that's how I use it for showing an error. However, I need to do other things with markup based on whether there was an error or not (e.g. open the modal). Is there a way to somehow use number of errors in an if condition?

Comment: Oops - sorry, now I'm re-reading the question. Will have to investigate. The interface mentions a HttpServletRequest, otherwise I'd have assumed a mismatch between PortletRequest (e.g. ActionRequest) and ServletRequest, but this doesn't seem to be the case - at least with regards to the interface. Stay tuned, can't do it immediately...

Comment: I totally missed the PortletRequest version of the SessionErrors interface. See my update to the JSP snippet and the last paragraph explaining